# How do I share data between sibling components in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application with 3 sibling components, they are able to access and update the variable "data". They are connected to the router, but the data I want to pass is sensitive (api endpoints to determine discounts) so I cannot use cmp2/:data

Component 1 has an object called data and Components 2 and 3 need to receive this data object. I think this can be done with a shared service, but I'm not quite sure how to get this event emitter to work..

My index.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Component 1:

```
<button [routerLink]=['cmp2/']>Go to Comp 2 </button>
<button [routerLink]=['cmp3/']>Go to Comp 3 </button>
```

Components 2 and 3:

```
{{ data }}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have asked to share the data between sibling components we can achieve it by using *BehaviourSubject* in service.

The BehaviorSubject holds the value that needs to be shared with other components. These components subscribe to data which is simple returning the BehaviorSubject value without the functionality to change the value.

Service.ts

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class Service {
       private data = new BehaviorSubject("")
       currentData = this.data.asObservable();

 constructor() { }

 setData(data) {
      this.data.next(data);
 }
```

Component1.ts

```
import { Service } from '../service.service';

export class component1 implements OnInit {

data: any;

constructor (private service: Service) {}

sendDataToService() {
     this.service.setData(this.data);
}
```

Component2.ts

```
import { Service } from '../../service.service';

export class component2 implements OnInit {

constructor ( private service: Service ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.currentData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: You forget `@Injectable`?

Answer (score 42):

As it looks like you are looking to redirect to those components, what you can do is have an event emitter on component one, that on click will emit the data to the parent(of all 3).  Then in the parent you would catch the emit, and assign that to data that you pass into the other components.

Component1

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }                          from '@angular/router';

@Component(...)
export class Component1 {
    @Output() redirect:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    data:any = {text: "example"};

    constructor(private router:Router){}

    changeComponent(url:string){
        this.redirect.emit(data);//emits the data to the parent
        this.router.navigate([url]);//redirects url to new component
    }
}
```

Component2 & Component3

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class Component2 {
    @Input() data:any;
}
```

Parent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class Parent {
    parentData:any;
}
```

Parent.html

```
<component1 (redirect)="parentData=$event"></component1>
<component2 [data]="parentData"></component2>
<component3 [data]="parentData"></component3>
```

---

Another option, if you don't have a parent, is to have a service, that you inject into each parent, and then for the receivers hook into the OnInit lifecycle hook.  This works because services are a singleton if in a provider of a shared module.

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharingService{
    private data:any = undefined;

    setData(data:any){
        this.data = data;
    }

    getData():any{
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Component1

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';
import { Router }         from '@angular/router';
import { SharingService } form './sharing.service';

@Component(...)
export class Component1 {

    data:any = {text: "example"};

    constructor(private router:Router,
        private sharingService:SharingService){}

    changeComponent(url:string){
        this.sharingService.setData(this.data);
        this.router.navigate([url]);//redirects url to new component
    }
}
```

Component2 & Component3

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharingService }    form './sharing.service';

@Component(...)
export class Component2 implements OnInit{
    data:any;

    constructor(private router:Router,
        private sharingService:SharingService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.data = this.sharingService.getData();
    }
}
```

Make sure you add it to providers array of the module.

Module

```
import { SharingService } from './sharing.service';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [ SharingService ]
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Joo I'm implementing your elegant solution and will let you know if it works.

Comment: @Joo data saved in shared service will get erased when use hit browser refresh button, how can we handle that ??

Comment: @ZeeshanChaudhary probably no longer an issue, but for future readers, there are generally 2 ways to store data between sessions: local storage or on the server.  If you use local storage, you can save it to the browser, and then when the service initializes check if there is data stored in local storage, and use that.  Local storage is only on one computer, and will be removed with cookies.  For more permanent solution, you must send the data to the backend server, and store it there, and then make a call to the backend to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple receiver `components`, Best way is to use a **singleton** shared `service`. Because later if you create more receiver `components`, emitting to each and every individual `component` would not be appropriate.

Incase you need :

Simple explanation for `Output` and `EventEmitter`

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Demo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DemoService {
  public message = new BehaviorSubject('');
  getMessage = this.message.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
  setMessage(message:string){
    this.message.next(message);
  }
}
```

acomp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DemoService} from '../demo.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-acomp',
  templateUrl: './acomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./acomp.component.css']
})
export class AcompComponent {
  message1: string = 'Hello1';
  message2: string = 'Hello2';
  book = {title:'Heheh'};
  constructor(private demoservice:DemoService){
    this.demoservice.setMessage(this.message1);
    console.log(this.message1 ," Message send by the a comp");
  }
}
```

bcomp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DemoService} from '../demo.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bcomp',
  templateUrl: './bcomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bcomp.component.css']
})
export class BcompComponent {
  message!:string;
  constructor(private demoservice:DemoService){
    this.demoservice.getMessage.subscribe(message=>this.message=message);
    console.log(this.message,"Message Received by the b comp");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has the facility to share data between siblings through `$emit, $broadcast and $on` in angular’s `$scope` and `$rootScope` event system.

```
<div>
  <div ng-controller="SiblingOneCtrl1 as sib1" class="ng-scope">
    // SiblingOneCtrl
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="SiblingTwoCtrl2 as sib2" class="ng-scope">
    // SiblingTwoCtrl
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('SiblingOneCtrl1',
  function SiblingOneCtrl1 ($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$on('rootScope:emit', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Emit!'
  });

  $scope.$on('rootScope:broadcast', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Broadcast!'
  });

  $rootScope.$on('rootScope:broadcast', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Broadcast!'
  });

});

app.controller('SiblingOneCtrl2',
  function SiblingOneCtrl2($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$emit('rootScope:emit', 'Emit!'); // $rootScope.$on
  $rootScope.$broadcast('rootScope:broadcast', 'Broadcast'); // $rootScope.$on && $scope.$on

});
```

also, you can follow [this](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/) and [this](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/25/communication-between-collaborating-directives-in-angular/)

Comment: Sorry eigenharsha, I appreciate the answer, but this is Angular not AngularJS